# How to test cassandra DAOs in Quarkus

Tags: cassandra, integration-testing, quarkus

I'd like to write some DAO-Tests in Quarkus for a cassandra database.
I googled this test framework: https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-quarkus/tree/main/test-framework
Now I have a problem, that I need to use a private docker container registry to pull images from.
But I have no idea how to configure the cassandra-quarkus-test-framework.
So did someone of you have an idea where to configure the URL of the docker registry in that framework?
Or do you have other ideas how to test Cassandra DAOs in Quarkus?

EDIT: Here is a working example project: https://github.com/edward-fakhouri/quarkus-cassandra-playground
Only the test class "CustomerDaoTest" is not working. Here I need some examples how to test the dao.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I have been using https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit for a long time, it is capable and not require docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have tested the cassanda-unit embedded database and it is working for Linux/Unix systems but not for Windows systems. So it won't work for testing the code while developing (in a windows os) but it will work, when running the tests in CI/CD environment. I'm only a bit happy with that solution.
Thanks @ozkanpakdil for suggesting this solution.